# Why it works in its own space?

Tags: javascript, constructor, prototype

```
function Member(){
  this.x="hello";
};
var test = new Member();
Member.prototype.x = "test";
console.log(test.x);
//hello
```

I originally wrote like this for making a constructor expecting its output would be "test". But it didn't work, the result was "hello".
But when I made the constructor to the below one, it worked.

```
function Member(){
  Member.x="hello";
};
```

I want to know how it was worked. Thanks.

Comment: [Object prototypes - Learn web development | MDN](https://developer.mozilla.org/en-US/docs/Learn/JavaScript/Objects/Object_prototypes)

Comment: In what sense does "it work"? `this.x` is the *x* property of an instance, `Member.x` is the *x* property of the *Member* function object. The strings assigned to each are entirely independent, changing one will not affect the other.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

When you perform `new Member()`, a couple of things happen, [MDN](https://developer.mozilla.org/en-US/docs/Web/JavaScript/Reference/Operators/new#description) described these steps quite nicely:

> 1. Creates a blank, plain JavaScript object. For convenience, let's call it `newInstance`.
> 2. Points `newInstance`'s [[Prototype]] to the constructor function's `prototype` property, if the prototype is an [`Object`](https://developer.mozilla.org/en-US/docs/Web/JavaScript/Reference/Global_Objects/Object). Otherwise,
>    `newInstance` stays as a plain object with `Object.prototype` as its
>    [[Prototype]]. ...
> 3. Executes the constructor function with the given arguments, binding `newInstance` as the [`this`](https://developer.mozilla.org/en-US/docs/Web/JavaScript/Reference/Operators/this) context (i.e. all references to
>    `this` in the constructor function now refer to `newInstance`).
> 4. If the constructor function returns a [non-primitive](https://developer.mozilla.org/en-US/docs/Web/JavaScript/Data_structures#primitive_values), this return value becomes the result of the whole `new` expression.
>    Otherwise, if the constructor function doesn't return anything or
>    returns a primitive, `newInstance` is returned instead. (Normally
>    constructors don't return a value, but they can choose to do so to
>    override the normal object creation process.)

That means that in your examples:

- `test` is the `this` object created in your `Member` constructor function when called with `new` (ie: the "instance").
- `test`'s [[Prototype]]<sup>1</sup> points to the object `Member.prototype`. Meaning that all properties on the object `Member.prototype` can be access via `test` (if not "shadowed" on `test`)

When you use `test.x`, we first look for `x` on the instance created by `new Member()` (ie: the `this` object that was created in your function and returned). If `x` cannot be found on the instance itself, then the prototype (object stored at the `__proto__` property) is checked for `x` (and then if it can't be found on the prototype we then check the prototype's prototype and so on).

In your first example, since we're able to find `x` on the object instance itself with the value of `"hello"` it logs `"hello"` and doesn't check the prototype (the `x` on the instance "shadows" the `x` on the prototype).

In your second example, since your function doesn't add any properties to `this`, the instance returned by `new Member()` doesn't have an `x` property like the first example did (its an empty object `{}`), and so we check the prototype (which from step 2 above we see is `Member.prototype`), which does have an `x` property set to `"test"`, and so it logs `"test"`. Performing `Member.x` adds `x` as a property to your function object, but doesn't impact the instance created by using `new`.

---

<sup>1</sup> Note that as [RobG](https://stackoverflow.com/users/257182/robg) pointed out, the use of `__proto__` is [deprecated](https://developer.mozilla.org/en-US/docs/Web/JavaScript/Reference/Global_Objects/Object/proto). The spec uses an internal slot, `[[Prototype]]`, on the constructed object instance and is used to point to the constructor function's `.prototype` property. Avoid using `__proto__` and instead use methods such as [`Object.getPrototypeOf()`](https://developer.mozilla.org/en-US/docs/Web/JavaScript/Reference/Global_Objects/Object/getPrototypeOf), [`Object.create()`](https://developer.mozilla.org/en-US/docs/Web/JavaScript/Reference/Global_Objects/Object/create) or [`Object.setPrototypeOf()`](https://developer.mozilla.org/en-US/docs/Web/JavaScript/Reference/Global_Objects/Object/setPrototypeOf) when you need to access / set the object for the `[[Prototype]]` slot (although, the use of `setPrototypeOf()` should still be used sparingly due to performance reasons)

Comment: The use of `__proto__` is [deprecated](https://developer.mozilla.org/en-US/docs/Web/JavaScript/Reference/Global_Objects/Object/proto) and supported by ECMA-262 only as a [legacy feature for web browsers](https://262.ecma-international.org/#sec-object.prototype.__proto__). In ECMA-262 (and more recently in MDN), the object internal prototype property is referred to as `[[Prototype]]`.

Comment: @RobG thanks, you're right, I've added a note now on __proto__ being deprecated